# ANR: Native method - android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce

Tags: android, anr

We have in some games in Android a lot of issues with ANR.

The most important I want to ask you is about Native method - android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce

Do you have the same ANR Problem? Did you resolved? How?

Thank you :)

I try to put all the last SDKs version in the game